# Swiping to delete items of recyclerview doesnt work

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I am trying to add this function to my `RecyclerView`, that when I swipe one item either to the left or the right it gets deleted.
But when I execute my App I can't even swipe one of the items.
Appreciate any help

```
new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback= new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mExampleList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            saveData();
        }
```

By the way this `RecyclerView` is not located in my MainActivity but in a Fragment that can be opened from the Drawer menu in the MainActivity, so maybe the problem lies there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have finally found the problem.
I just had to initialize the ItemTouchHelper in the method where the `RecyclerView`is built instead of in the onCreate method.

So this is what the code looks like:

```
 private void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTochHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTochHelperCallback=new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mExampleList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```